# DOMDOCUMENT - not getting content correctly

Tags: xml, domdocument

I am struggling to find the individual cell contents of these below `<td>`s from the below simplified source HTML:

```
<table id='tableid'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='/link?variable=15'>Text1</a></td>
            <td class='color-4'>Text2</td>
            <td>Text3</td>
            <td>Text4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='/link?variable=27'>Text5</a></td>
            <td class='color-1'>Text6</td>
            <td>Text7</td>
            <td>Text8</td>
        </tr>
        [...] // Shortened for brevity
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Shortened code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($this->DOM);
$table = $doc->getElementById('tableid');
print_r($table);
foreach ($table->childNodes as $table_node) {
    if (!empty($table_node->tagName) && $table_node->tagName == 'tbody') {    
        if (!empty($table_node->childNodes)) {
            foreach ($table_node->childNodes as $table_row) {
                print_r($table_row->childNodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following (shortened) feedback from the code above at table level:

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => table
    [schemaTypeInfo] =>
    [nodeName] => table
    [nodeValue] =>
        Text1Text2Text3Text4
        Text5Text6Text7Text8
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
);
```

And at row level:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 0
)
```

Only thing out of the ordinary with the HTML is the single quotes in the `<a>` tags and the `id` of the table, however, I doubt it is causing the hassle, as it is finding the tableid just fine like that.

At this point, I am not seeing childNodes for the table rows, and the nodeValue of table is the text with tags stripped from its childNodes. I am expecting to be able to traverse through to `<tr>`s and `<td>`s

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: I am expecting to get Text1, Text2, Text3, etc. as separate values from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with an html document, it's probably simpler to use xpath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$exp = "//table/tbody//tr";
$targets = $xpath->evaluate($exp);
for ($i = 0; $i < $targets->length; $i++) {
    echo $targets->item($i) ->nodeValue. "\n";
}
```

Or using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($targets as $target) {
            $entries = $xpath->evaluate('.//td',$target);
            foreach ($entries as $entry){
                echo $entry->nodeValue . "\n";
             }
            echo "\n";
    }
```

Output:

```
Text1
            Text2
            Text3
            Text4
        
Text5
            Text6
            Text7
            Text8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. XPath solved the issue for me wonderfully!